# Separate time and date

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to separate date and time from ionic storage but it not working. This my example code

```
if (this.storage.get('pickupTime')) {
    this.storage.get('pickupTime').then((pickupTime) => {
        console.log('pickupTime =>', pickupTime);
    });
}
```

When I log it to the console it looks like this `pickupTime => 14/02/2021 03:01 am`.

What should I do, I want it to print the time only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a datetime parsing library like [moment](https://momentjs.com/).

```
import moment from 'moment';
...
// Create a moment object from the Date Object and get only the time part from it
const timeStr = moment(pickupTime).format("HH:mm");
```

if pickupTime is stored as a string, not a Date object, then you can pass the format to moment() as well.

```
const timeStr = moment(pickupTime, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm a").format("HH:mm a");
```

Comment: I got this `pickupTime => Invalid date` when console log

Comment: Is pickupTime a Date object or a string? If it is a string, what format you have stored it in?

Comment: Edited my answer to handle the case where pickupTime is stored as a string, not a Date